Why does $r = \cot \theta \csc \theta$ draw an exact parabola?
It's easy to prove that a parabola has polar coordinates $$r = \cot \theta \csc \theta.$$ What, however, is the intuition behind this? How does the product of $\cot$ and $\csc$ define a parabola?
In contrast, the rectangular coordinates formula $y = x^2$ is clear: the height increases as the square of the width.
The alternate form $$r = \frac{\cos \theta}{\sin^2 \theta}$$ is perhaps clearer, explaining why $r \to 0$ as $\theta \to \pi/2$, and why $r \to \infty$ as $\theta \to 0$.  It also shows $r$ as proportional to the ratio between the direction vector's $x$ component and the square of its $y$ component.  But beyond that, I'm at a loss to explain how it sweeps a parabola.

(I will look at the parabola $y = x^2$ instead, which is $r = \tan\theta\sec\theta$ in polar coordinates.)
Let's think it through from the polar perspective. Going at an angle of $\theta$ from the $x$-axis, how far do we have to go in order for the vertical distance traveled to be the square of the horizontal distance?
The square of one distance being equal to another distance is actually a pretty uncommon thing to see in Euclidean geometry, because it's not scale independent: it requires first choosing a unit. Really, what we're saying is that the horizontal distance is the geometric mean of the vertical distance and $1$.
To construct a geometric mean, we build a right triangle. Let $O$ be the origin (where the parabola starts), let $P$ be the point on the parabola, let $Q$ be its projection onto the $x$-axis, and let $R$ be a point on $PQ$ such that $\triangle OPR$ is a right triangle:

Then $OQ^2 = PQ \cdot QR$. So $P$ ends up on the parabola if we go far enough that $QR = 1$.
In this diagram, both $\triangle OPQ$ and $\triangle OQR$ are right triangles, with $\angle POQ = \angle ORQ = \theta$ and $QR = 1$. Now we use these right triangles to write $r = OP$ in terms of $\theta$:
$$
    r = OP = OQ \sec \theta = (QR \tan \theta) \sec \theta = \tan\theta \sec\theta.  
$$
I don't know how intuitive this is, but the diagram above is at least the diagram we want to draw if we want to see where the trig functions come from.

The point about the scale invariance is also why the OP's formula for $r$ should really have a constant factor in it, so $r$ has units of length.

Very insightful, esp. the part that homogeneity precludes comparing a squared length to a length without setting up a unit; geometrically, we do this with a G.M. and a right triangle (I think this insight is from Descartes).  This answers the question completely.  Would you mind sharing some insight how you developed this?

Fixed the typos and added a clarification about the parabola, thanks! (Insight about how I came up with this is harder to come by; I was very proud of myself for introducing the geometric mean in the right triangle, and then just played around with ratios for a while until I came up with something good. Initially, I was solving for $x = OQ$, but then I realized that if we write $x = r\cos\theta$, that's based on a triangle that's in the diagram already.)

I have an answer now (just posted) that I believe does not depend on Cartesian coordinates in any way, not even through such notions as "the vertical distance traveled [is] the square of the horizontal distance." It's based on the parabola as a section of a right circular cone.

Recall that $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$. In particular, $\cot(\theta)=x/y$. Plugging this into your equality you will immediately get $y^2=x$, which is the usual equation for a parabola.

Yes, the OP acknowledges that "it's easy to prove that a parabola has polar coordinates..." - the question is tagged what is the intuition behind this? Why does the product of $\csc$ and $\cot$ sweep a parabola?

I don't think this answers the question for the reason mentioned above.

@ultralegend5385 I think this is a perfectly good answer, because $\cot\theta=x/y$ and $\csc\theta=r/y$; by plugging these in it becomes obvious that the equation implies $y^2=x$ as long as $r\neq 0$. I'm not sure what makes this less intuitive than Misha Lavrov's answer (which admittedly is very pretty). It goes directly to the equation, whereas the geometric approach yields a figure that we don't normally associate with a parabola -- it just happens to work due to algebra, just like this answer.

Unlike the other answer, this method gives you Cartesian equations for a large variety of trig-based polar equations, so if you have such an equation and want to know what shape it is, you'll be able to find out this way as long as you recognize the shape from its Cartesian equation.

In short, if the way you recognize a parabola is by the fact that one of its Cartesian coordinates is the square of the other -- which all the answers to this question rely upon -- then the insight that will unlock the secret of polar representation is that the polar representation is just a clever encoding of the Cartesian formula. All of the answers make use of this fact. This one merely does it more directly than the others.

The issue I have is that the OP already acknowledged in the question that the Cartesian coordinate formula makes sense to them, they were looking for an explanation through the polar coordinate formula. This answer does not seem to address that at all.

@ultralegend5385 My issue is that I don't find any of the other answers more "intuitive" than this one. Every single answer so far is based on the equation $y^2=x$, even the accepted answer (OK, $y=x^2$ in that case, but still Cartesian). I think the only reason that answer is accepted is because it put sufficient layers of disguise around the Cartesian equation. I don't rule out the possibility of an explanation that arrives at $r = \cot \theta \csc \theta$ without ever referring to Cartesian coordinates, but what if we don't find one? Why can't the two formulas share an intuition?

@DavidK I think the intuition you're looking for is different from the intuition I was trying to provide, which is "where are the right triangles that these trig functions come from?" I agree that I still don't know if there's a way to make the polar equation fundamental, without going through $y = x^2$.

@MishaLavrov "... a way to make the polar equation fundamental, without going through $y=x^2$." You did manage to make a more elegant interpretation of the application of the triangle $\triangle OPQ$ than this answer does. (This answer implicitly relates to $\triangle OPQ$ through the formulas $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$.) By "more elegant" I mean you keep everything about the geometry rather than using algebra to put things into the final form. I didn't mean to belittle that achievement or to say the answer wasn't valid, just that this answer is valid in a similar way.

I had actually written up a complete answer along similar lines to this one before noticing that the two answers were essentially equivalent. So I deleted my answer, not because I didn't like it, but because it would have been repetitious.

Another way to see that there is a parabola behind, is by
$$r^2=\frac{\cos^2 \theta}{\sin^4 \theta}=\frac{\cos^4 \theta}{\sin^4 \theta}+\frac{\cos^2 \theta}{\sin^2 \theta}=\overbrace{\cot^4\theta + \cot^2 \theta}^{x^2+y^2}$$
which is compatible with a polar parametrization for the cartesian equation $x=y^2$.

Shifting the focus at the origin the equation for the parabola $x=y^2$ becomes
$$r=\frac{1}{2(1-\cos \theta)}$$
which can lead to some more interesting facts to check its properties.
Indeed the intercept at a point $(x,y)=(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)$, assuming wlog $y>0$, is
$$y-r\sin \theta=\frac{1}{2r\sin \theta}\left(x-r\cos \theta\right)$$
and at $y=0$ the intercept is
$$x=-2r^2\sin^2 \theta + r\cos \theta=-r$$
which is related at the reflective property.

image credits

If you think of the representation of trigonometric functions with respect to a triangle in a unit circle, you might be able to get a starting point for your intuition.

In this case,
$$\sin t = y$$
$$\tan t = \frac{y}{x}$$
So when we talk about the product of $csc$ and $cot$ we are actually talking about the reciprocals.
$$\csc t\cot t = \frac{1}{\sin t}\cdot\frac{1}{\tan t}$$
$$= \frac{1}{y}\cdot\frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y^2}$$
As you can see, this sets up a quadratic relationship between $x$ and $y$ where $x$ is the square of $y$.
Why then does it need to be the reciprocal functions? Why could we not use $\sin t\tan t$?
Without trying to unpack the full reasoning, maybe it would help to focus on the $\sin t$ since it is contributing to the $y$ component (and is therefore easier to think about than the $\tan t$ which has two moving parts so to speak).
If you just think about the output of $\sin$ it ranges between $-1$ and $1$. If you square this, it will just give you another number in $[-1, 1]$. So if you take the reciprocal, it will give you a "full" range that is proportional to the input angle.

Let the objective be to construct a parabola with vertex at $r=0$
and focus at $(r,\theta) = \left(\frac14, 0\right)$.
The construction will be via a Dandelin sphere tangent to the coordinate plane at a point $P$.
We construct a cone tangent to this sphere such that the distance from the apex $A$ of the cone to the coordinate plane is the same as the diameter of the sphere;
the cone then intersects the coordinate plane in a parabola,
and the focus of the parabola is at $P$.
To help the description, extend the polar coordinates on the plane to cylindrical coordinates by adding a $z$ axis.
Let the radius of the sphere be $\frac14$, tangent to the $r,\theta$ coordinate plane at $(r,\theta,z) = \left(\frac14,0,0\right)$.
Let $A$ be at $(r,\theta,z) = \left(0,0,\frac12\right)$ on the $z$ axis.
Projecting all of these objects orthogonally on the $r,\theta$ plane, we have the figure below, where $Q$ is a point on the parabola at coordinates $(r,\theta)$.

Note that in this projection, the sphere projects to a circle that cuts off a segment of length $\frac12\cos\theta$ along the line $AQ$.
Now let's take a cross-section along a plane that contains the $z$ axis and passes through $Q$. This plane intersects the sphere in a circle of diameter
$\frac12\cos\theta$ tangent to the $z$ axis and with its center at $z=\frac14$,
as in the figure below.

The circle subtends and angle $2\phi$ at $A$ where $\tan\phi = \cos\theta$.
Therefore
$$ r = \frac12 \tan(2\phi) = \frac12\left(\frac{2\tan\phi}{1 - \tan^2\phi}\right)
= \frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta} = \cot\theta\csc\theta. $$
Now if you find a construction of a parabola via a Dandelin sphere to be intuitive
(and I hope you do; it's a good intuition to have in your toolbox),
that's a completely geometric construction motivating the final sequence of equations, and no $x$ or $y$ coordinates were considered in the process.
